# How to put a div one after the other?

Tags: html, css

I am REALLY new to HTML and I am doing a project for my web design class on a movie.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbo1ftu9/

```
<div id="footer">
<a href="D:/MOVIE REPORT/akira.htm" title="GO BACK?"><img src="D:/IMAGES/goback.gif">
```

This is how my code looks right now, apologies for its messiness. I want to put a footer that goes after the main body, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKlgi.jpg

I tried using a table like the teacher asked me and it did not work at all. Please help!

Comment: In what way did you “*try using a table*” and how did it “*not work at all*”? Please take a read of both the “*[mcve]*” and “*[ask]*” guidelines, then [edit] your question so we can help you without guessing.

Comment: Please share your code of footer so that we can understand what you are trying before

Comment: Take a look into CSS Grids. This will help.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

1997 called, they want their `<table>` back.

You can just add a new `div` after the first, and add some separation with CSS:

```
<div>
  Content
</div>

<footer>
  <a href="/">Go back</a>
</footer>
```

```
body {
  background: #333
}

footer, div {
  background: white
}

div {
  height: 300px
}

footer {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```